# How to determine size of fixed length array database column using JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

Given this PostgreSQL table with a fixed length array column :

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id         integer,
    values     integer[4],
);
```

Will JOOQ code generation create a java constant or method that provides the max number of elements that can be stored in the values column (i.e. 4)?

After reading through JOOQ documentation on code generation and support for SQL arrays, I couldn't find anything specific about fixed length arrays. Also, nothing jumps out at me in the generated code that provides this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, version 3.9 of jOOQ doesn't know any fixed size or size limit of a database array (neither with PostgreSQL array types nor with Oracle `VARRAY` types).

I have registered feature request [#5932](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5932) for this.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Are you aware of plans to add this feature to a future version of JOOQ?

Comment: @RDub: I've registered a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5932, but no promises. This sounds like a non trivial thing to add to the existing type system, and it's probably not used very often.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it directly answers the question I asked. I added my own answer to the residual issues with fixed length PostgreSQL arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question in part because I was worried about array overruns in the PostgreSQL database. After researching a way to use straight SQL to determine the size constraint, I noticed the [PostgreSQL ARRAY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) documentation makes the statement :

> As before, however, PostgreSQL does not enforce the size restriction in any case.

Based on that statement, it would appear using the array constraint to enforce size is not necessary since all array columns appear to be treated as variable length. So even if one could retrieve the PostgreSQL array size constraint through JOOQ, Straight SQL, or any other means, why bother?

Comment: Hah, interesting detail! But perhaps, you could write a trigger to enforce the constraint?